# Optional FilterExpression AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am currently working on an AWS project, the following issue came up:

```
export async function main(event, context, callback) {
const params = {
    FilterExpression: 'parent_id = :parent_id',
    TableName: 'product',
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ':parent_id': event.queryStringParameters.parent_id
    },

};

try {
    const result = await dynamoDbLib.call("scan", params);
    callback(null, success(result.Items));
} catch (e) {
    callback(null, failure({ status: false }));
}
```

This all works fine. But I want to be able to NOT give an expressionattribute, so that it returns ALL of my objects instead of just the ones with the matching parent_id.

Any help is much appreciated!

Thank you in advance,

Bram

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a `FilterExpression`, thus you have to provide `ExpressionAttributeValues` for the filter expression. You simply need to remove the `FilterExpression` and `ExpressionAttributeValues` parameters if you want the `Scan` operation to return all table items.

Comment: But I want to be able to do both, once with the filters, and once without the filters.

Comment: So it sounds like you need 2 separate pieces of code then? Or add a conditional statement in your code to perform different scan operations based on the availability of `queryStringParameters.parent_id`? You're going to have to add some actual logic to your code instead of relying on the DynamoDB scan function to somehow interpret what you want.

Comment: Thank you! I was thinking to problematic, the problem is alot easier than I thought :)